# Copiar valor de um input com document.execCommand('copy') usando toLowerCase()?

Tags: javascript

Preciso copiar o valor de um input para a área de transferência, até o momento fiz desta forma:

```
$("#valor").select();

try {
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
catch (e) {}
```

Porém, gostaria de que este valor copiado fosse todo em letras minúsculas, ou seja, aplicando um .toLowerCase(), porém não estou conseguindo e tentei pesquisar mas não obtive resultados... Alguém saberia me instruir de como fazer?

Answer (score -3):

Após algumas pesquisas cheguei no Clipboard API, API projetada para substituir o acesso à área de transferência usando document.execCommand(), que foi deprecado.

Neste caso é possível copiar para a área de transferência o próprio texto de um elemento ou de uma variável.

A solução foi:

```
var valor = $("#valor").val().toLowerCase();

navigator.clipboard.writeText(nrRegistro).then(function() {
    console.log("success");
}, function(err) {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Deixo de referência para caso alguém tenha os mesmos problemas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API